# What's wrong with my algorithm code?

Tags: c, algorithm

The question I am trying to solve is this:

> You are given a rectangular cake, represented as an r × c grid. Each cell either has an evil strawberry, or is empty. For example, a 3 × 4 cake may look as follows:
>
> The cakeminator is going to eat the cake! Each time he eats, he chooses a row or a column that does not contain any evil strawberries and contains at least one cake cell that has not been eaten before, and eats all the cake cells there. He may decide to eat any number of times.
>
> Please output the maximum number of cake cells that the cakeminator can eat.
>
> The first line of input contains two integers r and c (2 ≤ r, c ≤ 10), denoting the number of rows and the number of columns of the cake. The next r lines each contains c characters — the j-th character of the i-th line denotes the content of the cell at row i and column j, and is either one of these:
>
> '.' character denotes a cake cell with no evil strawberry;
>
> 'S' character denotes a cake cell with an evil strawberry.
>
> Output the maximum number of cake cells that the cakeminator can eat.

Here is a sample input that should produce `8`:

```
3 4
S...
....
..S.
```

My code gives `12`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
    int cake[r][c];
    int i, j, cnt=0, cou=0, a=0, b=0, cell=0;
    getchar();    //reject "\n" 
    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
            scanf("%c", &cake[i][j]);
        }
        getchar();
    }
    // debug
    //    printf("%c\n", cake[0][0]);
    //        printf("%c\n", cake[0][1]);
    //            printf("%c\n", cake[0][2]);
    //                printf("%c\n", cake[0][3]);
    //                    printf("%c\n", cake[2][2]);
    for(i=0;i<r; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
            cnt++;
            if(cake[i][j]=='S') {
                cnt=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(cnt>0) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
        for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
            cou++;
            if(cake[i][j]=='S') {
                cou=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(cou>0) {
            b++;
        }
    }
    cell=cnt + cou - a*b;
    printf("%d", cell);
    return 0;
}
```

By debugging, I found that `if(cake[i][j] == 'S')` is wrong, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: cake[i][j] is storing integer value. cast 's' into integer before comparing it.

Comment: format your `for` loops in one line, you will find your code much easier to read

Comment: @AlterMann - nope. it's a character not string.

Comment: I'm surprised your code even compiles. You cannot define arrays dynamically in C. So `int cake[r][c];` should fail, since the compiler does not know what `r` and `c` are at compile time.

Comment: @ShashankJain, oops, you are right, sorry

Comment: @DanielR. Dynamic arrays (i.e. run-time sizing) was added in C99.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ymLgnk it's done !. i took character array. and handled all cases. look into it  !

Comment: @KlasLindbäck You're right. My bad.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &cake[i][j]);` - This code is only correct if `cake[i][j]` is of type `char`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Now I know how to write the right code.Not only the wrong array type,but also some details was also unsatisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Corrected Code, changes are notified by "<---change"**

http://ideone.com/ymLgnk

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
    char cake[r][c]; <--- Change
    int i, j, cnt=0, cou=0, a=0, b=0, cell=0;
    //reject "\n" <--- Change
    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
            scanf("%c", &cake[i][j]);
        }
        <--- Change
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
            cnt++;
            if(cake[i][j]=='S') {
                cnt=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(cnt>0) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
        for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
            cou++;
            if(cake[i][j]=='S') {
                cou=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(cou>0) {
            b++;
        }
    }
    cell=cnt + cou - a*b;
    printf("%d", cell);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You trashed the input function and failed to fix the error in the algorithm. Changing array type to `char` fixed a problem, but removing the skipping of the newlines didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help to point out that the wrong of array type.But unfortunately, your code is wrong.And now I know how to write the right code.

Comment: i didn't checked logic in the first place. BTW it's a simple Breadth First Search (BFS) question.

Answer (score 0):

I used char arrays, and input each row as a string, which saves fiddling with the input when `scanf()` was scanning for single chars. Also I checked the entries (except length allowed for `strg`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXIND 10

char cake[MAXIND][MAXIND+1];
char strg[100];

int main()
{
    int numrows, numcols, row, col, emptyr=0, emptyc=0, cell;
    scanf("%d %d", &numrows, &numcols);
    if (numrows < 2 || numrows > MAXIND || numcols < 2 || numcols > MAXIND)
        return;   // bad cake size

    // input each line
    for (row=0; row<numrows; row++) {
        scanf ("%s", strg);
        strupr (strg);
        strncpy (cake[row], strg, MAXIND);
    }

    // check each row
    for (row=0; row<numrows; row++) {
        for (col=0; col<numcols; col++)
            if(cake[row][col]=='S')
                break;
        if (col == numcols)
            emptyr++;   // whole row is empty
    }

    // check each column
    for (col=0; col<numcols; col++) {
        for (row=0; row<numrows; row++) 
            if(cake[row][col]=='S')
                break;
        if (row == numrows)
            emptyc++;   // whole column is empty
    }

    // there are two ways to calculate
    // each empty row lacks the number of empty columns
    cell = emptyr*(numcols-emptyc) + emptyc*numrows;
    printf("%d\n", cell);

    // or each empty column lacks the number of empty rows
    cell = emptyr*numcols + emptyc*(numrows-emptyr);
    printf("%d\n", cell);
    return 0;
}
```